# Simple Image Gallery Cropped Images

Tags: extensions

I have a new website using the Simple Image Gallery extension. I have it working pretty well it seems. However when I crop an image in my image directory, the original is still displayed in the image gallery, which is not the behaviour I want (nor expect). So, is it, in fact, possible to display the cropped image, instead of the original in the image gallery? And if so, what else do I have to do, apart from crop it and save it in the image directory to make this work? Thanks.